# Trouble formulating a regular expression for use with sed to extract column values

Tags: linux, shell, sed, text-parsing

`ls -la`

```
Permissions   links  Owner  Group  Size   Date        Time    Directory or file
-rwxr--r--     1     User1  root    26    2012-04-12  19:51    MyFile.txt
drwxrwxr-x     3     User2  csstf  4096   2012-03-15  00:12     MyDir
```

when I write the `ls -la | sed -n 's/\(..........\)   \(.*\).*$/\1/p'`
It show the following output.

```
Permissions   links  Owner    Group  
 -rwxr--r--     1     User1   root    
 drwxrwxr-x     3     User2   csstf
```

But I need the following output.

```
Size  
 26    
4096
```

Note that I need to use `sed`. And also I need to sort the sizes from largest to smallest and need shows the largest 3 files only.

Comment: This is a job for `awk`.  Nearly all system having `sed` also have `awk`. `ls -la | awk '{print $5}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general caveat applies: `awk` is the better tool for the job.

Here's a simpler `sed` solution:

```
ls -la | sed -E 's/^(([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+){5}.*/\2/'
```

- works with both spaces and tabs between columns
- takes advantage of repeating capture groups only reporting the *last* captured instance - in this case, the 5th column
- **caveat**: will not work correctly with filenames with embedded spaces

In case **only spaces** separate the columns - which is the case with `ls` output, the command simplifies to:

```
ls -la | sed -E 's/^(([^ ]+)[ ]+){5}.*/\2/'
```

To **skip the first input line** you have several options, but the simplest is to prepend `1d` to your `sed` program:

```
ls -la | sed -E '1d; s/^(([^ ]+)[ ]+){5}.*/\2/'
```

(Other options:

Use `tail` to skip the first line:

```
ls -la | tail +2 | sed -E 's/^(([^ ]+)[ ]+){5}.*/\2/'
```

More generically, use `sed` to ignore lines that do not have at least 5 columns:

```
ls -la | sed -E -n 's/^(([^ ]+)[ ]+){5}.*/\2/p'
```

- `-n` suppresses default output
- appending `p` to the substitution command only produces output if a substitution was made

)

To **show only the 3 largest files** (a requirement added later by the OP), courtesy of @JS웃:

```
ls -la | sed -E '2d; s/^(([^ ]+)[ ]+){5}.*/\2/' | sort -nr | head -3
```

The above will not output the header line, however.
To **include the header line**, use (courtesy of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11857/54804) unix.stackexchange.com answer):

```
ls -la | sed -E '1d; s/^(([^ ]+)[ ]+){5}.*/\2/' | 
  { IFS= read -r l; echo "$l"; sort -nr | head -3; }
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Only problem is during the output of  file sizes, it shows i the first line `total 65492`. Actually I don't need that

Comment: If I want `ls -la` to output through pipe, how should I write the script. For example `ls -la | prog.sh`. The program needs to show largest three files and total number of lines

Comment: @codeSlayer789: You keep expanding the scope of your question. These additional questions are quite basic, and you ask to just be _given_ the answer, which is not how SO works; just a few pointers, so you can figure out the rest by yourself: put the part of the pipeline starting with `sed` into a script file with appropriate shebang line (e.g., `#!/bin/sh` and make the file executable (`man chmod`); see `man wc` for how to count lines.

Answer (score 4):

Use the right tool for the job. If you're processing columns, `awk` is a better solution:

```
ls -la | awk '{print $5}'
```

Given your `ls -la` output, that should generate:

```
Size
26
4096
```

If, for some bizarre reason you *cannot* use the correct tool, the following `sed` command will work, but it's rather ugly:

```
sed 's/[ \t]*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-.*//;s/[ \t]*Date.*//;s/^.*[ \t]//'
```

It works by removing from the year column (`9999-`) and preceding tabs/spaces, to the end of the line.

Then it does something similar for the header.

Then it just removes everything from line start to the final tab/space, which is now just before the size column.

I know which one *I'd* prefer to write and maintain :-)

Comment: yeah but I need to use `sed`.  That's the reason I ask all about this. @paxdiablo

Comment: @codeSlayer789: _why_ do you need to use `sed`? I don't try to eat my dinner with a chainsaw or cut down a tree with a haddock.

Comment: yeah I accept it. But, the question I am doing, they ask me to use `sed` to do that and sort them. @paxdiablo

Comment: @codeSlayer789, suggest you check that all those gaps are spaces rather than tabs. Also suggest you check the _actual_ input data matches what you've shown. The command works fine for your given sample assuming it's spaces. That's the major problem with using sed over awk - awk will automagically handle different column separators.

Comment: actually it's tab @paxdiablo

Comment: @codeSlayer789, then you need to use tabs in the regular expression. I'll update it to handle both.

Comment: @codeSlayer789: Where do the tabs come from? `ls` doesn't use tabs in its output.

Comment: Actually I guess like that by looking the output. I don't know how to check exactly whether it is a tab or a space. What's you idea. @mklement0

Comment: @codeSlayer789: There are several options; simplest here: pipe the output to `cat -t` and see if the output contains `^I` in place of the whitespace between columns.

Comment: But the thing is above answer also not getting the output what I want. It gives only the file names. Not the file sizes

Comment: @mklement0 it does not contain `^I`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way with GNU `sed`:

```
ls -la | sed -r '1d;s/([^ ]+ *){4}([^ ]+).*/\2/'
```

If your version of `sed` does not support `-r` option, then use `-E`.

Comment: If you use `-E`, it'll work on both Linux (GNU `sed`) and BSD-derived systems, including OSX.

Comment: JS웃: Thank you, I really appreciate it - I'll add your `sort ... | head ...` command - with proper attribution to my answer; @codeSlayer789: Please add the sort requirement to your answer, and make it clear that it was added later.